# How do I create a new csv file after merging four as a dataframe?

Tags: pandas, csv, dataframe

I am trying to merge four csv and create a new one with this data:
import pandas as pd
My code:

```
df1 = pd.read_csv(r"a.csv")
df2 = pd.read_csv(r"b.csv")
df3 = pd.read_csv(r"c.csv")
df4 = pd.read_csv(r"d.csv")
finaldf = pd.concat([df1, df2, df3,df4])

print(finaldf.head())
finaldf.to_csv("Compiled_Project",encoding='utf-8')
```

The code runs without breaking, however, the output in the path is not a .csv file. it is just a blank file with the name "Compiled_Project". 
Any reason for this error?

Comment: Does `finaldf.head()` show anything?

Comment: What is `len(finaldf)`?

Comment: len(finaldf) = 33120 @coldspeed

Comment: @JoergVanAken yes it shows [5 rows x 162 columns

Comment: Is the file actually blank (i.e., 0 bytes) or is it just your mac Finder not recognising the file without an extension? ;)

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried opening the csv using pandas?

Immediately I notice you've not included .csv in the file name.

Change the last line to:

```
finaldf.to_csv("Compiled_Project.csv",encoding='utf-8')
```

Comment: thanks this works but for some reason all the data of the merged files are adjacent to each other. I want the format to be df1 data first then below that df2.... and so on

Comment: In pd.concat use the argument axis=1, so:    finaldf = pd.concat([df1, df2, df3,df4], axis=1)

Answer (score 0):

csv files only have one set of columns, specified at the start of the file. So your dataframes also need to have a common set of columns. If they do, then the csv looks as I think you're imagining it should:

```
$ echo -e "a,b,c\n1,2,3" > a.csv
$ echo -e "a,b,c\n4,5,6" > b.csv
$ echo -e "a,b,c\n7,8,9" > c.csv
$ echo -e "a,b,c\n10,11,12" > d.csv
$ python3
>>> import pandas as pd
>>> df1 = pd.read_csv(r"a.csv")
>>> df1
   a  b  c
0  1  2  3
>>> df2 = pd.read_csv(r"b.csv")
>>> df3 = pd.read_csv(r"c.csv")
>>> df4 = pd.read_csv(r"d.csv")
>>> finaldf = pd.concat([df1, df2, df3,df4])
>>> finaldf
    a   b   c
0   1   2   3
0   4   5   6
0   7   8   9
0  10  11  12
>>> finaldf.to_csv("Compiled_Project.csv",encoding='utf-8',index=False)
>>> exit()
$ cat Compiled_Project.csv 
a,b,c
1,2,3
4,5,6
7,8,9
10,11,12
```

The `index=false` flag is because you probably don't want the row labels (all the zeroes) in each row.